# How to split a file using delims?

Tags: python

I am trying to delete certain parts of a file while keeping others automatically in python.

For example:

If the file reads,

```
    proj: just some random text
    I can type too
    
    test: pejirqoe
    random stuff random stuff
    
    projectstuff: project is very cool
    erqwerqwerweqr
```

I would like to make it so I delete the text following test:, however, keep both proj: and projectstuff:

Comment: Did you write any code for this? If yes then please post it.

Comment: I have not yet written any code for this, I can post the code for the project I need it for, but It's fairly messy and won't really help with this.

Comment: If you're using some standart format to describe content of your file, there probably is some python lib to work with that format. If you're using your own format, maybe it would be a good idea not to, and use json or yaml instead.

Comment: It's a file written with the raw gmail api data and there is very limited documentation on gmail api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
take = True
with open("path/to/input") as infile, open('path/to/output', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        if ":" in line:
            section = line.lstrip().split(":",1)[0]
            take = section != 'test'  # we don't want anything in the test section
        if take:
            outfile.write(line)
```